# How to prevent a specific request to redirect from http to https in SSL configuration?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jboss7.x

I am facing one issue regarding ssl. Basically i want to stop redirection of only one request from http to https in Jboss 7.

According to the requirement all http request should be redirected to https but can we configure one url or request which should not be redirected https.

```
For example :- http://myhost/test/testId=1002
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have post this question on server fault also.